# Adding a new module from Oxygen Xml Editor throws error when hit from http get but works fine when deployed through Roxy?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, oxygenxml, roxy

I have a `WebDAV` connection and have a directory structure of my `Xquery` codebase. When I right click and create a new `xqy` file from the `Oxygen Xml Editor's` file explorer, define a `module namespace`, my logic and later import the library module to the main `xqy` file, I am getting the following error:

> 404 Not Found
>
> Old Error

[image]
So whenever I import my new module I get this error.

```xml
<error:error xsi:schemaLocation="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error
   error.xsd" xmlns:error="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
  <error:code>XDMP-MODNOTFOUND</error:code>  
  <error:name>err:XQST0059</error:name>  
  <error:xquery-version>1.0-ml</error:xquery-version>  
  <error:message>Module not found</error:message>  
  <error:format-string>XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: (err:XQST0059) Module
  C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Modules\Marklogic\appservices\search\search.xqy 
 not found</error:format-string>
  <error:retryable>false</error:retryable>
  <error:expr/>
    <error:data>
     <error:datum>C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Modules\Marklogic\appservices\search\search.xqy</error:datum>
    </error:data>   
    <error:stack>
      <error:frame>
        <error:uri>/index.xqy</error:uri>           
      <error:xquery-version>1.0-ml</error:xquery-version>
    </error:frame>   
  </error:stack>
</error:error>
```

which is obviously not the case.

But surprisingly, when I deploy the same single file using Roxy, it works just fine.

I don't think that the Oxygen is pointing to somewhere else because when I make code changes in existing file or the same file which got deployed through Roxy, it is reflected immediately. So what's happening?

Comment: Check to see what the permissions look like **before** and **after** the Roxy deployment for a new module. It may be that the default permissions for the module create via WebDAV are too restrictive(or there are none) and the Roxy deployment is setting the appropriate permissions that are giving you read/execute on that module.

Answer (score 0):

Check your module database's directory creation setting. It should be set to "automatic" for use with WebDAV (Roxy defaults it to manual, which is generally preferable if you're not using WebDAV).